# How do I use iText7 to OCR a multi page PDF?

Tags: java, pdf, itext, ocr, tesseract

I have used iText PdfRender, which converts a non-OCR PDF to an image, after which I used iText PdfOcr to convert that image to an OCR'd PDF. Is there a tool that lets me perform this process in *one step*?

It would also be helpful if there was some documentation on how I can process **multi-page** PDFs using PdfRender, which I can't seem to find. The following is the code I used to convert 1 image to an OCR PDF document.

```
import com.itextpdf.pdfocr.OcrPdfCreator;
import com.itextpdf.pdfocr.tesseract4.Tesseract4LibOcrEngine;
import com.itextpdf.pdfocr.tesseract4.Tesseract4OcrEngineProperties;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;


public class img2pdfocr {

    static final Tesseract4OcrEngineProperties tesseract4OcrEngineProperties = new Tesseract4OcrEngineProperties();
    private static List LIST_IMAGES_OCR = Arrays.asList(new File("image1.jpg"));
    private static String OUTPUT_PDF = "F:\\ITEXT_workspace\\jumpstart\\bizdoc.pdf";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        final Tesseract4LibOcrEngine tesseractReader = new Tesseract4LibOcrEngine(tesseract4OcrEngineProperties);
        tesseract4OcrEngineProperties.setPathToTessData(new File("F:\\ITEXT_workspace\\jumpstart\\TESS_DATA_FOLDER"));

        OcrPdfCreator ocrPdfCreator = new OcrPdfCreator(tesseractReader);
        try (PdfWriter writer = new PdfWriter(OUTPUT_PDF)) {
            ocrPdfCreator.createPdf(LIST_IMAGES_OCR, writer).close();
        }
    }

}
```

**EDIT**

As pointed out in the comments, I need not use pdfRender, iText core itself can be used to extract images from a PDF. Use [this](https://github.com/itext/i7js-book/blob/develop/src/main/java/com/itextpdf/samples/book/part4/chapter15/Listing_15_30_ExtractImages.java) for the code. You can check on this [documentation](https://kb.itextpdf.com/home/it7kb/faq/how-to-get-the-co-ordinates-of-an-image)

Comment: first of all, what are your input files? You mention they are non-OCR PDF. Are they scanned documents? If they are, and if the scanner created them by putting a single bitmap image into each page, a better choice than rendering would be extracting, wouldn't it?

Comment: you do not need pdfRender to convert a PDF file into an image. I'm guessing that you have a PDF file that is _just_ am image, but you can use Core to extract that image, and then run it through pdfOCR

Comment: @mkl yes they are scanned documents. I'm new to this so it would be helpful if you could tell me how extraction is different from rendering and how I can do it using iText(or any other module).

Comment: @AndréLemos the files are multi-page PDFs, where each page is a single image (what a scanner would output). As far as I know, pdfRender is a part of itext-core, so I don't exactly understand how else I can use Core to extract the image if not for pdfRender.

Comment: @ayman_006, pdfRender is an add-on to Core. You are free to use it to render the PDFs as images, but it would make more sense to just use Core to extract the images from the PDFs. You can check on this [documentation](https://kb.itextpdf.com/home/it7kb/faq/how-to-get-the-co-ordinates-of-an-image) or this GitHub [example](https://github.com/itext/i7js-book/blob/develop/src/main/java/com/itextpdf/samples/book/part4/chapter15/Listing_15_30_ExtractImages.java) how to extract images from a PDF file.

Comment: I would propose that you try following the examples linked by @André, usually that approach gives rise to the best results. Beware, though, there are scanners which try to be smart, analyze the scanned image and cut it into separate parts in different formats; if image extraction returns such a collection of partial images for each page, rendering might turn out to be the easier solution for you.

Comment: @AndréLemos Thanks for the help, the link has been useful. Just want to know how I can convert multiple images (.png format) into one searchable PDF using PdfOcr. Using the given code I'm able to convert only a single image to a searchable PDF.

Comment: @mkl Thanks for the help.

Comment: @ayman_006, LIST_IMAGES_OCR is an array of images. Just pass multiple images to that array, and a single PDF document with multiple pages should be created

Comment: @AndréLemos Great! Thanks!